# Gift Program using C

Tags: c

I need to create a program that supposed to go like this:

"Each person sets aside a certain amount of money to give and evenly divides this money among all those s/he is gifting. No fractional currency exists. If the gifter decides to divide 5 among 2 friends, they would get 2 each with 1 left in the gifter's "account".

Given a group of n friends, the money each person in the group spends on gifts, and a list of friends to whom each person gives gifts, your goal is to determine how much more money each person gives than they receive."

It's supposed to read its input from a file called gift.txt.

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char name[11];
    int received;
    int given;
} ppl;

int main()
{
   FILE *file = fopen("D:\\Leo\\C Programs\\gift-giving\\gift.txt", "r");

   int n, i, j, k, amt, ng, gift, amtgvn, diff;
   char temp[11];
   char temp2[11];
   ppl friends[10];

   fscanf(file, "%d", &n);

   for(i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
      fscanf(file, "%s", temp);
      strcpy(friends[i].name, temp);
   }

   for(i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
       fscanf(file, "%s", temp);
       fscanf(file, "%d %d", &amt, &ng);

       gift = amt/ng;

       for(j=0; j<ng; j++)
       {
           fscanf(file, "%s", temp2);
           for(k=0; k<n; k++)
           {
               if(strcmp(friends[k].name, temp2)==0)
               {
                   friends[k].received = gift;
                   if(friends[k].received != 0)
                   {
                       friends[k].received += gift;
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       for(j=0; j<n; j++)
       {
           amtgvn = gift*ng;
           if(strcmp(friends[j].name, temp)==0)
           {
               friends[j].given = amtgvn;
           }
       }
   }

   for(i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
       diff = friends[i].received - friends[i].given;
       printf("%s %d", friends[i].name, diff);
   }

   fclose(file);

return 0;

}
```

I tried it with a gift.txt file containing:

```
5
ryan
becky
owen
joel
mimi
ryan
200 3
becky
owen
joel
owen
500 1
ryan
mimi
150 2
joel
owen
becky
0 2
mimi
joel
joel
0 0
```

The output is supposed to look like:

```
ryan 302
becky 66
owen -359
joel 141
mimi -150
```

But there is an error whenever I try to run it. A message appears saying the program has stopped working (I use Code Blocks on Windows).

What seems to be the problem in the code?

Comment: Today is good day to learn how to debug!

Comment: You would get better help with this on a site like cboard.

Comment: @ooga , Isn't this on-topic for StackOverflow? OP has code, explains what it is supposed to do, shows the expected output, and the current output.

Comment: @CoolGuy I'm sure it's on topic, but SO doesn't seem to be the best site for beginners. Look through the code. There's quite a bit that could be improved!

Comment: Here: `diff = friends[i].received - friends[i].given;` , `friends[i].given` may not be initialized.

Comment: Also the inner block in the loop where `gift` is supposedly added to `received` makes no sense to me. It assignes `received` and then tests it for `!=0`. You don't need a debugger but a rubber duck.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by division by `0`. The last line in your input file reads:

```
0 0
```

After those numbers are read, `amt = 0` and `ng = 0`. And then you proceed to compute `amt/ng`, which leads to an exception.

You need to add code to avoid that operation if `ng = 0`.

You can add

```
  if ( ng == 0 )
  {
     continue;
  }
```

just before the line

```
  gift = amt/ng;
```

You are also using uninitialized variables, which leads to undefined behavior.

Here's an updated `main`.

```
int main()
{
   char inputFile[] = "D:\\Leo\\C Programs\\gift-giving\\gift.txt";
   FILE *file = fopen(inputFile, "r");

   int n, i, j, k, amt, ng, gift, amtgvn, diff;
   char temp[11];
   char temp2[11];
   ppl friends[10];

   fscanf(file, "%d", &n);

   for(i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
      fscanf(file, "%s", temp);
      strcpy(friends[i].name, temp);
      friends[i].received = 0;
      friends[i].given = 0;
   }

   for(i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
      fscanf(file, "%s", temp);
      fscanf(file, "%d %d", &amt, &ng);
      printf("name: %s\n", temp);
      printf("amount: %d, ng: %d\n", amt, ng);

      if ( ng == 0 )
      {
         continue;
      }

      gift = amt/ng;

      for(j=0; j<ng; j++)
      {
         fscanf(file, "%s", temp2);
         for(k=0; k<n; k++)
         {
            if(strcmp(friends[k].name, temp2)==0)
            {
               friends[k].received += gift;
            }
         }
      }

      for(j=0; j<n; j++)
      {
         amtgvn = gift*ng;
         if(strcmp(friends[j].name, temp)==0)
         {
            friends[j].given = amtgvn;
         }
      }
   }

   for(i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
      diff = friends[i].received - friends[i].given;
      printf("name: %s, received: %d, given: %d, diff: %d\n",
             friends[i].name,
             friends[i].received,
             friends[i].given,
             diff);
   }

   fclose(file);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @R Sahu for the help. There is no longer any error when I try to open the file, but it doesn't print the output. When I try to run the program, it outputs a blank console.

Comment: @Leo, Not sure why that happens for you. I get the expected output.

Comment: Maybe it's because of the compiler I'm using? What compiler are you using?

Comment: @Leo, I am testing it on a 64 bit Linux using gcc 4.8.2.

Comment: I use Code::Blocks on Windows 8. Do you happen to know a better compiler for Windows?

Comment: @Leo , Code::Blocks is an IDE, not a compiler. It is good. You can add some `printf`s to see where your program stops working.

Comment: It looks like I made a minor error. It's working now. Thank you so much everyone!